# CakePHP - deep model binding vs uses

Tags: cakephp, model, controller, cakephp-2.0

I recently read an old article it which this was suggested

> **Avoid using the $uses array** 
> You’ve got two completely unrelated models, but you need info from one in the controller of another. The
>   first idea is to add them to the $uses array. Hey, it’s easy and gets
>   the job done. Well, to make the long story short, it’s bad practice.
>   Think about your model bindings and ensure that models are really not
>   related to one another. Sometimes your User model is definitely not
>   related to CommentRating, but you absolutely need it in your users
>   controller. Well, just by chance it appears that
>   User->Post->Comment->CommentRating. It’s a deep binding that may not
>   be obvious at first, but by employing such a chain of models you can
>   easily avoid using the $uses array, when it’s really not necessary.

For the sake of readability/maintainability, I tend to prefer putting CommentRating in the uses array and then calling $this->CommentRating directly.

**Is using the $uses array really bad practice and if so why?**

Comment: That quote cuts a long story a bit too short. Why is it a bad practice? He doesn't even give one reason. I wouldn't pay too much attention to it. I'm no expert, but there are definitely cases when readability and common sense in your code is more important than a minute performance increase or whatever else avoiding $uses may provide. I'll be continuing to use $uses instead of obscure model chains like User->Post->Comment->Rating

Comment: @joshua.paling, add that as an answer and I'd happily upvote it :)

Comment: The reason it *was* bad was because Cake would load that model even if you didn't use it (for 1.x). In Cake 2.x lazy loading was implemented so it's not really an issue anymore (for performance wise).

Comment: @RobForrest OK thanks, I've added it as an answer. Don't know if the duplication will be frowned upon, but anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That quote cuts a long story a bit too short. Why is it a bad practice? He doesn't even give one reason. I wouldn't pay too much attention to it.

I'm no expert, but there are definitely cases when readability and common sense in your code is more important than a minute performance increase or whatever else avoiding $uses may provide. I'll be continuing to use $uses instead of obscure model chains like User->Post->Comment->Rating

EDIT: And as @tigrang added, with lazy loading of Models in Cake 2, there's not really a performance benefit anyway!